# Is DirectX really installed on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, directx

I ask because it sure doesn't feel like it. I have all my games installed on an external hard drive, and whenever I try running any of them on any Windows 7 computer which is supposed to already have DirectX 11 installed on it, I get one of the "The program cannot start because d_xinput.dll" is missing, or it might be "d3d9.dll" or some things like that, which usually means (as far as I know) that DirectX is NOT installed. When I install the DirectX SDK on the computer (My computer and one of my school computers) all games now immediately work, as the DirectX SDK also installs the runtime. On a fresh version of Windows 7, is DirectX 11 actually installed or does it need to be enabled somehow or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is (you can confirm by running `dxdiag` on a fresh install). However, the game may target an older version and thus you should install DirextX using either the End-User Runtime [Web Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35) or preferably the [Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8109) version.

Comment: I see. So on a fresh Windows 7 it literally ONLY supports Direct 11, and not any of the previous versions. I would have thought it would at least be backwards compatible to DirectX 9. That is so weird, not enough games support DirectX 11 to have only that version on Windows 7 without having to install the Runtime for version 9, 10 and 10.1 as well. Thank you, I've been wondering that for some time now.